# Flask App in Python listening to all IPs

Tags: python, flask

I am having trouble getting my Flask app working. This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')
```

When I run the app on my Linode server the console says: Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/. My actual server address is : http://139.xxx.xx.xx. However if I point my browser there I get the permission denied message. (my app.py file is in var/www/html/mysite.com/public_html. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this? I added in host = '0.0.0.0' as described by some other posts but this doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not enough to put the scripts into a public web folder. You have to deploy Flask, usually with a wsgi server and a webserver. Read http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

First check is to run wget from the console of the server:

```
wget 127.0.0.1:5000
wget <external ip of machine>:5000
```

If the first works but the second does not then your firewall is blocking the port. Which makes sense as 5000 is not open by default.

As a **temporary** testing measure you can disable your firewall using the command:

```
 /etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

**Do Not leave your firewall off**

Reactive it with:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables start
```

If this fixes the issue then you need to add a exception to iptables - or whichever firewall you are using.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT
```

if this works you can save the settings by running

```
sudo iptables save
```

Otherwise your added rule will be lost on reboot

but your probably don't want to always run flask on port 5000. Rather place something like apache or nginx in front of your flask app to do the heavy lifting or use mod_wsgi. Running on port 80 requires root privileges.

See [deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/)

Comment: ran wget and I got: Connecting to 127.0.0.01 (127.0.0.01)|127.0.0.1|:5000... failed: Connection refused. Added the port as you said. Run wget again and still have connection refused.